# Change ansible inventory based on variables

Tags: ansible

Can a playbook load inventory list from variables? So I can easily customize the run based on chosen environment?

```
  tasks:
  - name: include environment config variables
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - "../../environments/default.yml"
      - "../../environments/{{ env_name }}.yml"

- name: set inventory
  set_fact:
     inventory.docker_host = " {{ env_docker_host }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm in ansible 2.3 I can't use the `add_host` module (see Jack's answer and [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html) docs) and that would be a superior solution.  Therefore, I'll use a different trick to augment an existing ansible inventory file, reload and use it.

## hosts.inv

```
[remotehosts]
```

## main.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
    - name: include environment config variables
      include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - "../environments/default.yml"
        - "../environments/{{ env_name }}.yml"
    - name: inventory facts
      run_once: true
      set_fact:
        my_host: "{{ env_host_name }}"

    - name: update inventory for env
      local_action: lineinfile
        path=hosts.inv
        regexp={{ my_host }}
        insertafter="[remotehosts]" line={{ my_host }}

    - meta: refresh_inventory

- hosts: remotehosts
...
```

The pretasks process the environments yml with all the variable replacement etc and use that to populate `hosts.inv` prior to reloading via `refresh_inventory`

Any tasks defined beneath `- hosts: remotehosts` would execute on the remote host or hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use the `add_host` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html